# Cannot receive firebase analytics from IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-analytics

I'm developing a Flutter application for both Android and IOS. I'm collecting analytics using [firebase_analytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics) 8.2.0 package.

I have configured my application as described at the package [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics). My `Podfile` starts with `$FirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport = true`.

The problem is that I can only receive Android analytics.

[image]

My Code:

```
final FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();

void onGroupCreate(String groupId, double totalInvites, bool isStatus) {
      analytics.logEvent(
        name: "create_group",
        parameters: <String, dynamic>{
          'user_id': globals.user.userId,
          'group_id': groupId,
          'total_invites': totalInvites,
          'is_status': isStatus
        },
      );
    }
```

My `info.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>AppName</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>AppName</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.####-#######</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires contacts access to function properly.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires photos access to function properly.</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My `GoogleService-Info.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>####-######.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <key>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.####-######</string>
    <key>ANDROID_CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>####-######.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <key>API_KEY</key>
    <string>####-######</string>
    <key>GCM_SENDER_ID</key>
    <string>####</string>
    <key>PLIST_VERSION</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>BUNDLE_ID</key>
    <string>######</string>
    <key>PROJECT_ID</key>
    <string>####-####</string>
    <key>STORAGE_BUCKET</key>
    <string>####-####.appspot.com</string>
    <key>IS_ADS_ENABLED</key>
    <false></false>
    <key>IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED</key>
    <false></false>
    <key>IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>IS_GCM_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>GOOGLE_APP_ID</key>
    <string>#:####:ios:######</string>
    <key>DATABASE_URL</key>
    <string>https://####-####.firebaseio.com</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

What can cause that problem? Why can't I receive IOS analytics?

Comment: are all the right values for your app found in the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file?

Comment: I have compared `firebase_analytics` example's `GoogleService-Info.plist` file (https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics/example/ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist) to mine, and they are both the same.

Comment: I have also downloaded again my `GoogleService-Info.plist` and compared it to my current `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. The only change is that the `ANDROID_CLIENT_ID` is different. Does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem solved!

The problem was that **I didn't have an IOS data stream** in my project analytics property. All I had to do was to add a new IOS data stream and wait for analytics to show up after a day or two.

[image]
Steps to create new data stream on GA4 analytics

Comment: This should have already happened if you enabled analytics from Firebase.

Answer (score 9):

Firebase events are batched together and uploaded once every hour in order to prevent excessive battery drain on the devices.
On iOS when you background the app before the 1h upload target the events will be dispatched at this time in the background.
Once the events are uploaded there is a delay at about 3h before the data will show up in the Firebase Analytics dashboard. Also, the default day range excludes "today" so you only see events from yesterday.

in some cases, you need to run it on a real device and wait for 24h to see your app in the console

You can use [debug view](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) to test your events

Comment: Hello @Omar Mahmoud, thanks for your reply. It's been more than a week since the app run on a physical device. In addition I have tested the app with the debug view. There are no results :\

Comment: did you see events in debug view??

Comment: No nothing. I have also oped an issue to flutterfire team https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/7038#issuecomment-927262632

Comment: did you removed $FirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport = true just for testing ?

Comment: No I did not, the flutterfire team said it's no matter

Comment: Hey @Omar Mahmoud, I have found out that I don't have an IOS data stream in my property. Could it be the case? Adding a new IOS data stream and update the GoogleService-Info.plist file (firebase issue)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with in your code. Can you check once that have you added the iOS App Store id and bundle Id correctly? Because I faced the same problem once when I changed theApp Store id and the analytics stopped working.
Attaching the screenshot for your reference

[image]

Comment: @Mirnal Jail thanks for replying. I have verified that my App Store ID is identical to the one on `appStoreConnect`. What else do you think I should probably verify?